# Not understanding the behavior of the float and overflow attributes

Tags: css, css-float

```css
.title-strip{
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  }
.title1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  }
.title2 {
  float: right;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="title-strip title1">Title1</h1>
  <h1 class="title-strip title2">Title2</h1>
</div>
```

```css
.title-strip {
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
}

.title1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title2 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="title-strip title2">Title2</h1>
  <h1 class="title-strip title1">Title1</h1>
</div>
```

If the first h1 tag has the title1 class and the second has the title2 class, the text is on different lines.
But when the classes are swapped, the text is on separate lines. Why?

I read a stack overflow answer saying that 'BFCs don't allow descendant floats to escape them, nor do they allow sibling/ancestor floats to intrude into them', the result of words in the same line seems to go against this.
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow. Overflow: hidden makes no difference (please know this). When you use the float property on an item, it acts as inline-block even if it is block. In the example you have done here, the line in which it is located (the line it can go to) leans to the right and remains inline block.

I changed the colors so you could see more clearly. Please examine both samples carefully. in the first example, first the float right element is used, then the block element is used because they switch to the inside. But if the block element is used first then it continues from the bottom line without covering an area.

A small note: Float is no longer used frequently today. Instead, I suggest you choose structures such as display-flex or display-grid. They are both simpler and more useful for responsive appearance. I hope the description what I mean.

```css
.title-strip {
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
}

.title1 {
  /* overflow: hidden;   it doesn't make any difference. */
  background-color: yellow;
}

.title2 {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="title-strip title2">Title2</h1>
  <h1 class="title-strip title1">Title1</h1>
</div>
<div style="height: 75px;"></div>

<div>
  <h1 class="title-strip title2" style="margin-top: 50px;">Title2</h1>
  <h1 class="title-strip title1">Title1</h1>
</div>
<div style="height: 75px;"></div>
<div>
  <h1 class="title-strip title1">Title2</h1>
  <h1 class="title-strip title2">Title1</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: *Float is no longer used frequently today. Instead, I suggest you choose structures such as display-flex or display-grid.* : float has nothing to do with flexbox and CSS grid and will continue to be used *frequently* when float feature is needed. You cannot achieve everything with flexbox and CSS grid .(example of something that you can never achieve using flexbox or CSS grid: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62017850/8620333)

Comment: Of course, they don't count as identical. Actually, I mean, if the subject is to align left or right, it's more used and I mean simple. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

> I read a stack overflow answer saying that 'BFCs don't allow descendant floats to escape them, nor do they allow sibling/ancestor floats to intrude into them',

This is true not when the `overflow` is applyied to the float element but when the float element **is inside** the element where `overflow` is applyied

Here is a basic example to understand:

```css
.title-strip {
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
}

.title1 {
  background: red;
}

.title2 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="title-strip title2">Title2</h1>
</div>
<h1 class="title-strip title1">Title1</h1>

<br>
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
  <h1 class="title-strip title2">Title2</h1>
</div>
<h1 class="title-strip title1">Title1</h1>
```

See how in the second case the floated title is no more on the right of non-floated one because it's inside a div with `overflow:hidden`. It's own BFC so it no more interact with anything outside.